# cloud-init instance cloud config runcmd commands not executed in openstack

Tags: openstack, centos8, cloud-init, openstack-horizon

I am creating the instance in openstack with centos 8 hardened image. The configuration script as follows:

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - name: clouduser
    password: password
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) ALL']
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_pwauth: True
    lock_passwd: False
    plain_text_passwd:  password

runcmd:
       -  mkdir /run/test
```

here the user is created and I am able to login the instance but the commands in runcmd is not executed . even the runcmd log in `/var/log/cloud-init.log` is ran successfully but there is no folder is created in the /run/ folder and `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` is no change (runcmd module in cloud-config and script-user in cloud-finish are there and its executed successfully) but no commands got executed. the same commands if I run inside the instance its working fine. commands in bootcmd is also working but not with runcmd? I can't figure out why it's not being executed?

Comment: I don't have a centos but with an openSUSE VM it worked for me. Which cloud-init version are you using?

Comment: Its works well with community OS but not with the hardened image. the log has no error or failed messages for the run cmd and script-user modules. Unable to find where it went wrong?(No logs on other files in /var/log/ too). The only difference I am using the ext4 file system.  I am using the cloud-init version cloud-init-20.3-10.el8_4.5.noarch.rpm.

Comment: If it's a hardened image could it be some seliux/apparmor permission issue?

Comment: selinux set as disabled

Comment: Be sure to terminate your instance before running `terraform apply`. If the old instance is still running, sometimes Terraform gets confused between old state and new state. The way to ensure it doesn't is to terminate the old instance first.